# Shipping address gets blank after , adding new billing address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

Shipping address gets blanked , while adding new billing address
no errors in console , tried to debug and 
found that quote.shipping is getting unset in the js file default.js /Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer  in initObservable() method , just when adding the new billing address. https://prnt.sc/rtji6n

Any fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented this portion of code solves issue

```
  initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function () {
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveBillingAddress();
        }, this);

      /*  shippingRatesValidator.initFields(this.get('name') + '.form-fields'); */
    },
```